# Why can't rsyslogd find libgcc_s.so.1?

Tags: gcc, ubuntu, rsyslog, lxc, libgcc

Scenario: Running a debootstrapped Ubuntu 11.4 lxc guest on a Ubuntu 12.4 lxc host (both 64 bit)

Inside the lxc guest, rsyslogd is constantly crashing with SIGABRT stating:

```
libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work
0334.380551272:7f4128a84700: 
Signal 6 (SIGABRT) occured, execution must be terminated.
```

I'm not sure why libgcc_s.so.1  cannot be found.  If I run ldconfig -p:

```
$# ldconfig -p | grep libgcc
        libgcc_s.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        libgcc_s.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/libgcc_s.so.1
```

It is listed. And both of those links are valid.

How do I resolve this problem?

EDIT: objdump -T output by request:

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1:     file format elf64-x86-64

DYNAMIC SYMBOL TABLE:
00000000000025d8 l    d  .init  0000000000000000              .init
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 memset
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 abort
0000000000000000  w   D  *UND*  0000000000000000              __gmon_start__
0000000000000000  w   D  *UND*  0000000000000000              _Jv_RegisterClasses
0000000000000000  w   D  *UND*  0000000000000000              pthread_key_create
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 malloc
0000000000000000  w   D  *UND*  0000000000000000              pthread_once
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 free
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 strlen
0000000000000000  w   D  *UND*  0000000000000000              pthread_getspecific
0000000000000000  w   DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 __cxa_finalize
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 memcpy
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 dl_iterate_phdr
0000000000000000  w   D  *UND*  0000000000000000              pthread_cancel
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 calloc
0000000000000000  w   DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 pthread_mutex_lock
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 realloc
0000000000000000  w   DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 pthread_mutex_unlock
0000000000000000  w   D  *UND*  0000000000000000              pthread_setspecific
0000000000002de0 g    DF .text  0000000000000028  GCC_3.0     __mulvsi3
000000000000a8c0 g    DF .text  000000000000034c  GCC_4.3.0   __floatuntitf
000000000000c160 g    DF .text  00000000000001cf  GCC_4.3.0   __letf2
00000000000050a0 g    DF .text  0000000000000223  GCC_3.0     __modti3
0000000000009530 g    DF .text  0000000000000094  GCC_4.3.0   __unordtf2
0000000000004660 g    DF .text  0000000000000007  GCC_4.3.0   __bswapdi2
0000000000004ea0 g    DF .text  0000000000000045  GCC_4.2.0   __floatuntixf
0000000000011d80 g    DF .text  000000000000017f  GCC_4.3.0   __emutls_get_address
0000000000000000 g    DO *ABS*  0000000000000000  GCC_3.0     GCC_3.0
0000000000006ac0 g    DF .text  0000000000000a0f  GCC_4.3.0   __divtf3
0000000000002b70 g    DF .text  0000000000000032  GCC_3.0     __ucmpti2
0000000000000000 g    DO *ABS*  0000000000000000  GCC_3.3     GCC_3.3
0000000000000000 g    DO *ABS*  0000000000000000  GCC_3.4     GCC_3.4
0000000000002ac0 g    DF .text  0000000000000062  GCC_3.0     __ashrti3
0000000000002c60 g    DF .text  000000000000002d  GCC_3.0     __addvdi3
0000000000003270 g    DF .text  0000000000000036  GCC_3.4     __paritydi2
0000000000002cc0 g    DF .text  0000000000000042  GCC_3.4.4   __addvti3
00000000000032b0 g    DF .text  0000000000000039  GCC_3.4     __parityti2
00000000000098b0 g    DF .text  00000000000000ee  GCC_4.3.0   __floatsitf
0000000000002a60 g    DF .text  000000000000005f  GCC_3.0     __ashlti3
000000000000f830 g    DF .text  00000000000000e5  GCC_3.0     _Unwind_Resume
000000000000fa40 g    DF .text  00000000000000ab  GCC_3.3     _Unwind_Backtrace
0000000000000000 g    DO *ABS*  0000000000000000  GCC_3.4.2   GCC_3.4.2
00000000000036a0 g    DF .text  00000000000002e7  GCC_4.0.0   __muldc3
000000000000cb30 g    DF .text  0000000000000630  GCC_4.3.0   __multc3
000000000000cb30 g    DF .text  0000000000000630 (GCC_4.0.0)  __multc3
0000000000000000 g    DO *ABS*  0000000000000000  GCC_3.4.4   GCC_3.4.4
00000000000029d0 g    DF .text  0000000000000026  GCC_3.0     __negti2
000000000000c330 g    DF .text  0000000000000132  GCC_4.3.0   __eqtf2
0000000000003340 g    DF .text  000000000000004d  GCC_4.0.0   __powidf2
000000000000d160 g    DF .text  00000000000000a7  GCC_4.3.0   __powitf2
0000000000003180 g    DF .text  0000000000000009  GCC_3.4     __clzdi2
000000000000d160 g    DF .text  00000000000000a7 (GCC_4.0.0)  __powitf2
0000000000003190 g    DF .text  0000000000000022  GCC_3.4     __clzti2
00000000000052d0 g    DF .text  0000000000000113  GCC_3.0     __udivti3
0000000000009e00 g    DF .text  00000000000000fe  GCC_4.3.0   __floatditf
000000000000b540 g    DF .text  000000000000052f  GCC_4.3.0   __trunctfdf2
0000000000004b10 g    DF .text  00000000000000ca  GCC_3.0     __floattisf
0000000000009c80 g    DF .text  0000000000000173  GCC_4.3.0   __fixunstfdi
000000000000ac10 g    DF .text  0000000000000172  GCC_4.3.0   __extendsftf2
000000000000d6a0 g    DF .text  0000000000000008  GCC_3.0     _Unwind_GetLanguageSpecificData
000000000000d6c0 g    DF .text  0000000000000023  GCC_3.3     _Unwind_FindEnclosingFunction
000000000000d670 g    DF .text  0000000000000015  GCC_4.2.0   _Unwind_GetIPInfo
000000000000a2a0 g    DF .text  000000000000024a  GCC_4.3.0   __fixunstfti
00000000000112c0 g    DF .text  0000000000000132  GCC_3.0     __deregister_frame_info_bases
0000000000003150 g    DF .text  0000000000000010  GCC_3.0     __ffsdi2
0000000000003160 g    DF .text  000000000000001e  GCC_3.0     __ffsti2
00000000000047c0 g    DF .text  0000000000000039  GCC_3.0     __fixxfti
000000000000d6f0 g    DF .text  0000000000000008  GCC_3.0     _Unwind_GetDataRelBase
0000000000004070 g    DF .text  00000000000002ef  GCC_4.0.0   __divdc3
000000000000c470 g    DF .text  00000000000006b1  GCC_4.3.0   __divtc3
000000000000c470 g    DF .text  00000000000006b1 (GCC_4.0.0)  __divtc3
0000000000000000 g    DO *ABS*  0000000000000000  GCC_4.2.0   GCC_4.2.0
0000000000002dc0 g    DF .text  0000000000000020  GCC_3.0     __mulvdi3
0000000000002c00 g    DF .text  000000000000001b  GCC_3.0     __absvsi2
0000000000002e10 g    DF .text  000000000000028c  GCC_3.4.4   __mulvti3
00000000000112a0 g    DF .text  000000000000001a  GCC_3.0     __register_frame_table
0000000000008170 g    DF .text  00000000000013ba  GCC_4.3.0   __subtf3
000000000000af30 g    DF .text  000000000000016b  GCC_4.3.0   __extendxftf2
0000000000003990 g    DF .text  0000000000000413  GCC_4.0.0   __mulxc3
0000000000007e30 g    DF .text  000000000000033e  GCC_4.3.0   __negtf2
0000000000011210 g    DF .text  0000000000000072  GCC_3.0     __register_frame_info_table_bases
0000000000003390 g    DF .text  000000000000005f  GCC_4.0.0   __powixf2
0000000000004be0 g    DF .text  00000000000000ca  GCC_3.0     __floattidf
000000000000d6b0 g    DF .text  0000000000000008  GCC_3.0     _Unwind_GetRegionStart
000000000000a4f0 g    DF .text  00000000000003c1  GCC_4.3.0   __floattitf
0000000000004cb0 g    DF .text  000000000000002d  GCC_3.0     __floattixf
000000000000ba70 g    DF .text  0000000000000503  GCC_4.3.0   __trunctfxf2
0000000000011440 g    DF .text  00000000000001fd  GCC_3.0     _Unwind_Find_FDE
000000000000d690 g    DF .text  0000000000000008  GCC_3.0     _Unwind_SetIP
00000000000053f0 g    DF .text  000000000000018e  GCC_3.0     __umodti3
000000000000d660 g    DF .text  0000000000000008  GCC_3.0     _Unwind_GetIP
00000000000046d0 g    DF .text  000000000000006b  GCC_3.0     __fixunsxfdi
0000000000011130 g    DF .text  000000000000009a  GCC_3.0     __register_frame_info_bases
0000000000004940 g    DF .text  00000000000001ce  GCC_3.0     __fixunsxfti
0000000000004360 g    DF .text  00000000000002e6  GCC_4.0.0   __divxc3
0000000000002d40 g    DF .text  000000000000002c  GCC_3.0     __subvsi3
0000000000004740 g    DF .text  0000000000000037  GCC_3.0     __fixsfti
00000000000057c0 g    DF .text  00000000000012f7  GCC_4.3.0   __addtf3
0000000000000000 g    DO *ABS*  0000000000000000  GCC_4.3.0   GCC_4.3.0
00000000000030d0 g    DF .text  0000000000000024  GCC_3.0     __negvsi2
0000000000002bd0 g    DF .text  0000000000000025  GCC_3.0     __absvdi2
0000000000002980 g    DF .text  000000000000004c  GCC_3.0     __multi3
000000000000fa20 g    DF .text  000000000000001a  GCC_3.0     _Unwind_DeleteException
0000000000002c20 g    DF .text  0000000000000034  GCC_3.4.4   __absvti2
000000000000d600 g    DF .text  0000000000000008  GCC_3.3     _Unwind_GetCFA
0000000000002a00 g    DF .text  000000000000005f  GCC_3.0     __lshrti3
0000000000002bc0 g    DF .text  0000000000000002  GCC_3.4.2   __enable_execute_stack
00000000000031f0 g    DF .text  000000000000002c  GCC_3.4     __popcountdi2
0000000000000000 g    DO *ABS*  0000000000000000  GCC_4.0.0   GCC_4.0.0
0000000000003220 g    DF .text  0000000000000045  GCC_3.4     __popcountti2
0000000000002bb0 g    DF .text  0000000000000002  GCC_3.0     __clear_cache
000000000000c330 g    DF .text  0000000000000132 (GCC_3.0)    __netf2
000000000000c330 g    DF .text  0000000000000132  GCC_4.3.0   __netf2
0000000000004780 g    DF .text  0000000000000040  GCC_3.0     __fixdfti
00000000000099a0 g    DF .text  00000000000000db  GCC_4.3.0   __floatunsitf
00000000000095d0 g    DF .text  0000000000000190  GCC_4.3.0   __fixtfsi
0000000000002b30 g    DF .text  0000000000000032  GCC_3.0     __cmpti2
000000000000ad90 g    DF .text  0000000000000195  GCC_4.3.0   __extenddftf2
0000000000004650 g    DF .text  0000000000000005  GCC_4.3.0   __bswapsi2
000000000000f5d0 g    DF .text  000000000000016c  GCC_3.0     _Unwind_RaiseException
0000000000009f00 g    DF .text  00000000000000d3  GCC_4.3.0   __floatunditf
0000000000002c90 g    DF .text  000000000000002c  GCC_3.0     __addvsi3
0000000000004ce0 g    DF .text  00000000000000d6  GCC_4.2.0   __floatuntisf
000000000000bf80 g    DF .text  00000000000001df (GCC_3.0)    __gttf2
000000000000bf80 g    DF .text  00000000000001df  GCC_4.3.0   __gttf2
0000000000011410 g    DF .text  0000000000000021  GCC_3.0     __deregister_frame
0000000000000000 g    DO *ABS*  0000000000000000  GCC_3.3.1   GCC_3.3.1
00000000000031c0 g    DF .text  0000000000000005  GCC_3.4     __ctzdi2
0000000000004ef0 g    DF .text  00000000000001ab  GCC_3.0     __divti3
00000000000033f0 g    DF .text  00000000000002a5  GCC_4.0.0   __mulsc3
00000000000031d0 g    DF .text  000000000000001b  GCC_3.4     __ctzti2
0000000000011290 g    DF .text  0000000000000009  GCC_3.0     __register_frame_info_table
00000000000111e0 g    DF .text  0000000000000026  GCC_3.0     __register_frame
00000000000032f0 g    DF .text  000000000000004b  GCC_4.0.0   __powisf2
000000000000bf80 g    DF .text  00000000000001df  GCC_4.3.0   __getf2
0000000000004670 g    DF .text  000000000000002c  GCC_3.0     __fixunssfdi
000000000000b0a0 g    DF .text  000000000000049b  GCC_4.3.0   __trunctfsf2
00000000000074d0 g    DF .text  000000000000095f  GCC_4.3.0   __multf3
000000000000f920 g    DF .text  00000000000000f9  GCC_3.3     _Unwind_Resume_or_Rethrow
0000000000011f00 g    DF .text  0000000000000035  GCC_4.3.0   __emutls_register_common
0000000000002d10 g    DF .text  000000000000002d  GCC_3.0     __subvdi3
0000000000004800 g    DF .text  000000000000009f  GCC_3.0     __fixunssfti
0000000000002d70 g    DF .text  0000000000000042  GCC_3.4.4   __subvti3
0000000000009a80 g    DF .text  00000000000001fc  GCC_4.3.0   __fixtfdi
00000000000111d0 g    DF .text  0000000000000009  GCC_3.0     __register_frame_info
00000000000030a0 g    DF .text  000000000000002a  GCC_3.0     __negvdi2
0000000000005590 g    DF .text  000000000000022a  GCC_3.0     __udivmodti4
000000000000c160 g    DF .text  00000000000001cf (GCC_3.0)    __lttf2
0000000000003100 g    DF .text  000000000000004e  GCC_3.4.4   __negvti2
000000000000c160 g    DF .text  00000000000001cf  GCC_4.3.0   __lttf2
00000000000046a0 g    DF .text  0000000000000030  GCC_3.0     __fixunsdfdi
0000000000009fe0 g    DF .text  00000000000002b6  GCC_4.3.0   __fixtfti
0000000000011400 g    DF .text  0000000000000005  GCC_3.0     __deregister_frame_info
0000000000009760 g    DF .text  000000000000014b  GCC_4.3.0   __fixunstfsi
0000000000011800 g    DF .text  000000000000045c  GCC_3.3.1   __gcc_personality_v0
00000000000048a0 g    DF .text  0000000000000097  GCC_3.0     __fixunsdfti
000000000000d610 g    DF .text  0000000000000050  GCC_3.0     _Unwind_SetGR
0000000000004dc0 g    DF .text  00000000000000d6  GCC_4.2.0   __floatuntidf
0000000000003db0 g    DF .text  00000000000002b8  GCC_4.0.0   __divsc3
000000000000d5b0 g    DF .text  0000000000000048  GCC_3.0     _Unwind_GetGR
000000000000d700 g    DF .text  0000000000000008  GCC_3.0     _Unwind_GetTextRelBase
000000000000f740 g    DF .text  00000000000000ef  GCC_3.0     _Unwind_ForcedUnwind



/usr/lib32/libgcc_s.so.1:     file format elf32-i386

DYNAMIC SYMBOL TABLE:
00000000      DF *UND*  00000000  GLIBC_2.0   abort
00000000  w   D  *UND*  00000000              __gmon_start__
00000000  w   D  *UND*  00000000              _Jv_RegisterClasses
00000000      DF *UND*  00000000  GLIBC_2.0   realloc
00000000      DF *UND*  00000000  GLIBC_2.0   calloc
00000000  w   D  *UND*  00000000              pthread_key_create
00000000      DF *UND*  00000000  GLIBC_2.0   memset
00000000  w   D  *UND*  00000000              pthread_once
00000000      DF *UND*  00000000  GLIBC_2.0   free
00000000  w   D  *UND*  00000000              pthread_getspecific
00000000  w   DF *UND*  00000000  GLIBC_2.0   pthread_mutex_unlock
00000000      DF *UND*  00000000  GLIBC_2.0   memcpy
00000000      DF *UND*  00000000  GLIBC_2.0   strlen
00000000      DF *UND*  00000000  GLIBC_2.0   malloc
00000000  w   DF *UND*  00000000  GLIBC_2.0   pthread_mutex_lock
00000000  w   D  *UND*  00000000              pthread_cancel
00000000      DF *UND*  00000000  GLIBC_2.2.4 dl_iterate_phdr
00000000  w   DF *UND*  00000000  GLIBC_2.1.3 __cxa_finalize
00000000  w   D  *UND*  00000000              pthread_setspecific
00007c10 g    DF .text  000001d0  GLIBC_2.0   __moddi3
00002450 g    DF .text  00000038  GCC_3.0     __mulvsi3
0000c120 g    DF .text  00000225  GCC_4.4.0   __letf2
000103e0 g    DF .text  00000096  GCC_4.4.0   __unordtf2
000074b0 g    DF .text  0000000f  GCC_4.3.0   __bswapdi2
000187b0 g    DF .text  000001a8  GCC_4.3.0   __emutls_get_address
00000000 g    DO *ABS*  00000000  GCC_3.0     GCC_3.0
00002200 g    DF .text  0000003d  GCC_3.0     __ucmpdi2
0000a810 g    DF .text  0000156b  GCC_4.4.0   __divtf3
00002160 g    DF .text  00000060  GCC_3.0     __ashrdi3
00015da0 g    DF .text  000000d9  GLIBC_2.0   __frame_state_for
00000000 g    DO *ABS*  00000000  GCC_3.3     GCC_3.3
00000000 g    DO *ABS*  00000000  GCC_3.4     GCC_3.4
00002330 g    DF .text  00000069  GCC_3.0     __addvdi3
000028d0 g    DF .text  0000002f  GCC_3.4     __paritydi2
00013490 g    DF .text  00000033  GCC_4.4.0   __fabstf2
000020f0 g    DF .text  00000061  GCC_3.0     __ashldi3
000109a0 g    DF .text  000001e8  GCC_4.4.0   __floatsitf
00016100 g    DF .text  000000e2  GCC_3.0     _Unwind_Resume
00016300 g    DF .text  00000089  GCC_3.3     _Unwind_Backtrace
00000000 g    DO *ABS*  00000000  GCC_3.4.2   GCC_3.4.2
00002fd0 g    DF .text  00000408  GCC_4.0.0   __muldc3
00002050 g    DF .text  00000031  GCC_3.0     __negdi2
000037e0 g    DF .text  000018a8  GCC_4.4.0   __multc3
0000bd80 g    DF .text  00000185  GCC_4.4.0   __eqtf2
00002960 g    DF .text  00000054  GCC_4.0.0   __powidf2
00007950 g    DF .text  0000002c  GCC_3.0     __floatdidf
00002790 g    DF .text  00000020  GCC_3.4     __clzdi2
00002a20 g    DF .text  000001ad  GCC_4.4.0   __powitf2
00007de0 g    DF .text  00000104  GLIBC_2.0   __udivdi3
000112f0 g    DF .text  00000210  GCC_4.4.0   __floatditf
00012720 g    DF .text  0000067b  GCC_4.4.0   __trunctfdf2
00007980 g    DF .text  0000002c  GCC_3.0     __floatdixf
00011050 g    DF .text  00000294  GCC_4.4.0   __fixunstfdi
000116f0 g    DF .text  0000039e  GCC_4.4.0   __extendsftf2
00013980 g    DF .text  0000000b  GCC_3.0     _Unwind_GetLanguageSpecificData
000139a0 g    DF .text  00000037  GCC_3.3     _Unwind_FindEnclosingFunction
00013950 g    DF .text  00000016  GCC_4.2.0   _Unwind_GetIPInfo
000076b0 g    DF .text  00000047  GCC_3.0     __fixxfdi
00017c20 g    DF .text  0000010f  GCC_3.0     __deregister_frame_info_bases
00002750 g    DF .text  0000002f  GCC_3.0     __ffsdi2
00000000 g    DO *ABS*  00000000  GCC_4.5.0   GCC_4.5.0
000139e0 g    DF .text  0000000b  GCC_3.0     _Unwind_GetDataRelBase
000075a0 g    DF .text  00000062  GCC_3.0     __fixunsxfsi
00005390 g    DF .text  000002f9  GCC_4.0.0   __divdc3
00005990 g    DF .text  00001b0f  GCC_4.4.0   __divtc3
00000000 g    DO *ABS*  00000000  GCC_4.2.0   GCC_4.2.0
00002490 g    DF .text  000001fe  GCC_3.0     __mulvdi3
00002260 g    DF .text  00000033  GCC_3.0     __absvsi2
00017be0 g    DF .text  00000033  GLIBC_2.0   __register_frame_table
0000dd70 g    DF .text  00002668  GCC_4.4.0   __subtf3
00011ea0 g    DF .text  00000293  GCC_4.5.0   __extendxftf2
000027f0 g    DF .text  00000050  GCC_3.4     __popcountsi2
000033e0 g    DF .text  000003f8  GCC_4.0.0   __mulxc3
0000d7c0 g    DF .text  000005a9  GCC_4.4.0   __negtf2
00017b00 g    DF .text  00000093  GCC_3.0     __register_frame_info_table_bases
000029c0 g    DF .text  00000054  GCC_4.0.0   __powixf2
00013990 g    DF .text  0000000b  GCC_3.0     _Unwind_GetRegionStart
00012da0 g    DF .text  000006ab  GCC_4.4.0   __trunctfxf2
00017da0 g    DF .text  000001de  GCC_3.0     _Unwind_Find_FDE
00013970 g    DF .text  0000000e  GCC_3.0     _Unwind_SetIP
00007ef0 g    DF .text  00000145  GLIBC_2.0   __umoddi3
00013940 g    DF .text  0000000b  GCC_3.0     _Unwind_GetIP
000027b0 g    DF .text  00000009  GCC_3.4     __ctzsi2
000077e0 g    DF .text  000000e0  GCC_3.0     __fixunsxfdi
00013450 g    DF .text  0000003e  GCC_4.4.0   __copysigntf3
000179c0 g    DF .text  000000a7  GCC_3.0     __register_frame_info_bases
000079b0 g    DF .text  00000059  GCC_4.2.0   __floatundisf
00005690 g    DF .text  000002fb  GCC_4.0.0   __divxc3
00007610 g    DF .text  00000047  GCC_3.0     __fixsfdi
000023a0 g    DF .text  0000003c  GCC_3.0     __subvsi3
00008230 g    DF .text  000025da  GCC_4.4.0   __addtf3
00000000 g    DO *ABS*  00000000  GCC_4.3.0   GCC_4.3.0
00002010 g    DF .text  00000035  GCC_3.0     __muldi3
00002690 g    DF .text  00000036  GCC_3.0     __negvsi2
000022a0 g    DF .text  00000050  GCC_3.0     __absvdi2
000162e0 g    DF .text  0000001f  GCC_3.0     _Unwind_DeleteException
000074c0 g    DF .text  00000062  GCC_3.0     __fixunssfsi
00002090 g    DF .text  0000005f  GCC_3.0     __lshrdi3
000138c0 g    DF .text  0000000b  GCC_3.3     _Unwind_GetCFA
00007660 g    DF .text  00000047  GCC_3.0     __fixdfdi
00002250 g    DF .text  00000005  GCC_3.4.2   __enable_execute_stack
00002840 g    DF .text  0000005b  GCC_3.4     __popcountdi2
00000000 g    DO *ABS*  00000000  GCC_4.0.0   GCC_4.0.0
00002240 g    DF .text  00000005  GCC_3.0     __clear_cache
0000bd80 g    DF .text  00000185  GCC_4.4.0   __netf2
00010b90 g    DF .text  000001a7  GCC_4.4.0   __floatunsitf
00010480 g    DF .text  000002b2  GCC_4.4.0   __fixtfsi
000021c0 g    DF .text  0000003d  GCC_3.0     __cmpdi2
00011a90 g    DF .text  00000401  GCC_4.4.0   __extenddftf2
00007530 g    DF .text  00000062  GCC_3.0     __fixunsdfsi
000074a0 g    DF .text  0000000a  GCC_4.3.0   __bswapsi2
00007a10 g    DF .text  00000037  GCC_4.2.0   __floatundidf
00015e90 g    DF .text  0000018e  GCC_3.0     _Unwind_RaiseException
00011500 g    DF .text  000001e7  GCC_4.4.0   __floatunditf
000022f0 g    DF .text  0000003c  GCC_3.0     __addvsi3
000028a0 g    DF .text  0000002a  GCC_3.4     __paritysi2
00007a50 g    DF .text  00000037  GCC_4.2.0   __floatundixf
0000bf10 g    DF .text  00000206  GCC_4.4.0   __gttf2
00017d60 g    DF .text  00000031  GLIBC_2.0   __deregister_frame
00000000 g    DO *ABS*  00000000  GCC_3.3.1   GCC_3.3.1
00007a90 g    DF .text  00000177  GLIBC_2.0   __divdi3
000027c0 g    DF .text  00000025  GCC_3.4     __ctzdi2
00002bd0 g    DF .text  000003f0  GCC_4.0.0   __mulsc3
00017ba0 g    DF .text  0000003a  GLIBC_2.0   __register_frame_info_table
00017ab0 g    DF .text  00000042  GLIBC_2.0   __register_frame
00002900 g    DF .text  00000054  GCC_4.0.0   __powisf2
00002780 g    DF .text  0000000c  GCC_3.4     __clzsi2
0000bf10 g    DF .text  00000206  GCC_4.4.0   __getf2
00007700 g    DF .text  0000006c  GCC_3.0     __fixunssfdi
00012140 g    DF .text  000005d4  GCC_4.4.0   __trunctfsf2
0000c350 g    DF .text  0000146a  GCC_4.4.0   __multf3
000161f0 g    DF .text  000000e2  GCC_3.3     _Unwind_Resume_or_Rethrow
00018960 g    DF .text  00000033  GCC_4.3.0   __emutls_register_common
000023e0 g    DF .text  00000069  GCC_3.0     __subvdi3
00000000 g    DO *ABS*  00000000  GLIBC_2.0   GLIBC_2.0
00010d40 g    DF .text  0000030d  GCC_4.4.0   __fixtfdi
00017a70 g    DF .text  0000003a  GLIBC_2.0   __register_frame_info
00002730 g    DF .text  00000014  GCC_4.3.0   __ffssi2
00008050 g    DF .text  000001d8  GCC_3.0     __udivmoddi4
000078c0 g    DF .text  0000008f  GCC_3.0     __floatdisf
000026d0 g    DF .text  0000005a  GCC_3.0     __negvdi2
00000000 g    DO *ABS*  00000000  GCC_4.4.0   GCC_4.4.0
0000c120 g    DF .text  00000225  GCC_4.4.0   __lttf2
00007770 g    DF .text  0000006c  GCC_3.0     __fixunsdfdi
00017d30 g    DF .text  00000023  GLIBC_2.0   __deregister_frame_info
00010740 g    DF .text  0000025a  GCC_4.4.0   __fixunstfsi
000181d0 g    DF .text  00000463  GCC_3.3.1   __gcc_personality_v0
000138d0 g    DF .text  0000006d  GCC_3.0     _Unwind_SetGR
00005090 g    DF .text  000002f1  GCC_4.0.0   __divsc3
00013850 g    DF .text  00000065  GCC_3.0     _Unwind_GetGR
000139f0 g    DF .text  0000000b  GCC_3.0     _Unwind_GetTextRelBase
00016020 g    DF .text  000000d8  GCC_3.0     _Unwind_ForcedUnwind
```

Comment: Let's find out what's in those files. `objdump -T /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 /usr/lib32/libgcc_s.so.1`

Comment: Added objdump details in post

Comment: Do an `ldd rsyslog`. Rsyslog, when compiled, often defines a static path to where it is looking for it's shared libraries. It might be looking for `libgcc_s.so.1` in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds somewhat similar to a [reported bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rsyslog/+bug/1024731) with rsyslogd on ubuntu. If you run out of options then upgrading to a later version of rsyslogd might be the way to go. You may have to build it from source.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference:
maybe it caused by 64bit system maybe NOT. I'm NOT sure, but I met some similar problems before, I just use 32bit lib, it seems OK. However, I'm now moving to openSUSE-12.X, seems problem solved...

Comment: Ya, I'm on 64bit. Moving to 32bit is not an option however

Answer (score -1):

You need to install `libgcc 32 bit`. If you check under `/libs` you will find a `x86_64-linux-gnu` folder but not `i386-linux-gnu`. This is due to unavailability of 32 bit library in 64 bit machine. You need to execute command:

`aptitude install libgcc1:i386`

After that you will find the folder `i386-linux-gnu` is created in `libs` and `libgcc_s.so.1` is existing under that. This should solve the problem.